# Display search results in their own buffer

Tags: helm, search, ivy

I've use helm and ivy with swiper the search is great but I like to be able to keep search results in a buffer, navigate and edit my code and switch back to my search results buffer.

Answer (score 4):

To do this with Ivy, press <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> (`ivy-occur`).

If the buffer contents have changed after the search, you can refresh the occur buffer with <kbd>g</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else may let you know how you can save a set of search results with Helm or Ivy and return to it later, after some editing.

But if you are *not set* on using only Helm or Ivy, you can do what you want in  other ways:

- Use command [`occur` or `multi-occur`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html) - or [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) to search. These are generally *line*-oriented, meaning that they search within each line - a line is the search context.
- Use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) -

  [Icicles search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) is similar to Swiper (Ivy search) or `helm-swoop`.  (Icicles search was doing Swiper 10 years before Swiper was introduced - 2005 vs 2015.)

  Like search with Helm or Ivy, Icicles search presents search hits as a set of *completion candidates*.  And you can incrementally change the set of search hits - it instantly reflects your current minibuffer input. And you can [progressively narrow](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion) the search (match *this* and *that* and *that* but **not** *that* and **not** *this*...).

  With Icicles you can easily [save](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Candidate_Sets) any set of completion candidates, either temporarily, across an Emacs session, or [persistently](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Persistent_Completions) (in a disk file), and you can retrieve them anytime, including (for a persistent saved set) in a future Emacs session.

  So yes, you can go back and forth between editing and searching your source code.  You don't lose a set of search hits just because you stop searching temporarily to edit the code you were searching.

Comment: Alt+X occur works for me. Thanks.